# How to read a WMV file in C#?

Tags: c#, byte, binaryfiles, wmv, readfile

First question i want to ask: "Is WMV file a binary file ?". And how to read a WMV file in bytes ?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [**AsfMojo**](http://asfmojo.codeplex.com/) on codeplex, all the parsing is done in managed code - assuming you *are* looking for a parser.

> AsfMojo is an open source .NET ASF parsing library, providing support
>   for parsing Windows Media Audio (WMA) and Windows Media Video (WMV)
>   files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

You can read it using a `FileStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is and you can read it into a byte array like so:

```
using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open("file.wmv", FileMode.Open)))
{
    byte[] array = b.ReadBytes(b.Length);
    b.close();
}
```

Note though that WMV files can be big and it might be better to read it in chunks at a time. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes.aspx#Y1080) on how to do that.

Comment: Thank for helping me. I want to ask you one more thing : I want to read information in WMV file as bitrate, language, metadata... I try to convert bytes array into String :
 textBox1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(file);
But it display : 0&?u?f???. So how do i can read information in WMV file

Comment: @HellDevil: You need a *WMV parser* unless you want to re-write all of this yourself, in this case check out the ASF file spec: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14995

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I have a thesis and i must write myself. I have read ASF specification and I understood struct of ASF file. But i want to read information of 1 ASF file and i don't know how to do it.

Comment: By the question you are asking I don't think you quite understood: the properties you want to read are stored in the WMV file header which you can parse using the ASF spec as your guide, just reading WMV as "a binary" file will just get you the bytes but not convey any semantics of those bytes, for that you need the spec

Comment: @HellDevil - BrokenGlass is right. If your intent is to parse out information from a WMV file, then his answer is the way to go. Trying to do this yourself is not only reinventing the wheel, but also a big undertaking. IF you absolutely need to do this yourself, then try googling "WMF file format" and look at the source code for ASFMojo and learn from that.

Comment: @BrokenGlass : I don't understand what you mean. I know a ASF file has objects as : Header object, Data Object, Index Object. In header object has information as i said above. So if i don't read wmv file as a binary file, how do i get information from wmv file ?

Comment: @icemanind : Actually I'm buidling a Streaming Video Server in Windows Media Http Streaming Protocol. So I have to parse out information from a WMV file to encapsulate and send to client. I have read ASFMojo's source code but it's difficult for me to understand.

Comment: @HellDevil: If you know this you should ask a specific question, stating what you have tried and what didn't work, your question currently looks like you don't even know where to start.

Comment: @BrokenGlass : Maybe you right. I have studied ASF specification for a time. I knew fairly clear about structure of a asf file. Now i try to parse out information of a asf file. I think it's a binary file and try to solve by Class and Function of C# relating to binary file. But it doesn't work. Can you give an advice for me to solve this problem ?